# Prove that $2\sqrt n \ge 1/\sqrt1+1/\sqrt2+\cdots+1/\sqrt n\ge2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) $

Tags: integration

For each positive integer $n$, prove that

$$2\sqrt n \geq 1/\sqrt1+1/\sqrt2+\cdots+1/\sqrt n\geq 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) $$

Answer (score 3):

Try induction:
  if $S_n = 1/\sqrt1+1/\sqrt2+...+1/\sqrt{n}$ 
then show

$  S_{n+1} \le 2\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \le 2\sqrt{n+1}$

This is quite doable, and I don't want to spoil your fun ;)

As for the right-hand side, there's some confusion as to what it is exactly. It can probably also be solved by induction.

Answer (score 2):

It summarizes the inequalities:
$$2(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})>\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$$

for $k=1,\cdots,n.$