# Prove that for every integer $n \ge 1$, $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+ ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\le 2\sqrt{n}$

Tags: induction

I understand that this is an induction question.

I start with the base case (n=1):

$$1 < 2  \tag{That works!}$$

Induction step: Assume the statement works for all $n = k$, Prove for all $n = k+1$

Assume $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+ ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\le 2\sqrt{k+1}$

I'm a bit confused as to where to go next, may I please have some assistance?

Comment: Assume for $k$ and prove it for $k+1$.

Comment: You know the left hand side is no greater than $$2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}.$$

Comment: You must assume the case up to $k$, not $k+1$. The $k+1$ case is the one you need to prove.

Comment: @DanielFischer With that information, how can I prove the desired conclusion? I'm really lost, please elaborate.

Comment: If you can show that $$2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leqslant 2\sqrt{k+1},$$ you're done. Showing that isn't too difficult.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768916/prove-that-2-sqrt-n-ge-1-sqrt11-sqrt2-cdots1-sqrt-n-ge2-sqrtn1-1/769181#769181

Answer (score 4):

*Hint* We have that $(2 x^{1/2})'=x^{-1/2}$. Now, think about $$\int_1^n x^{-1/2}dx$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, however we haven't ever used integration in this course (in fact, I haven't learned it at all).

Answer (score 0):

Compare the area below the red curve ($y=1/\sqrt{x}$) and the blue curve from $x=0$ to $x=\sqrt{n}$.

[image]

Comment: Did you see my answer? =)