# How to proove the following?

Tags: inequality, summation

For all non vanishing natural numbers prove:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{\sqrt k} \leqslant 2 \sqrt n $$

I tried a proof by recurrence but I can't figure out the solution

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Try a comparison with $\int_{0}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx.$

Comment: would you provide a link to the

Comment: would you provide a link to similar post please

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784258/prove-that-for-every-integer-n-ge-1-1-frac1-sqrt2-frac1-sqrt3, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768916/prove-that-2-sqrt-n-ge-1-sqrt11-sqrt2-cdots1-sqrt-n-ge2-sqrtn1-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285845/proof-for-inequality

Answer (score 2):

Since the function $f: x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a decreasing function, we have the inequality
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq \int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx.$$

Hence 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq \int_0^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 2 \sqrt{n}.$$